# django: ckeditor won't show up in admin

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-admin, django-ckeditor

I'm using Django 1.8 with Python 3.4, and I'm trying to add CKEditor to my django admin, but for some reason, it only shows up on my webpage, but not the admin. I'm following the steps described here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor/5.0.2

It said that the widget doesn't show up on the admin, then it's a problem with the jQuery URL, but I checked and there's no problem. Here's my settings file  where I have the configurations for the CKEditor:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog',
#'django_markdown',
'ckeditor',
'ckeditor_uploader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'qblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates',)],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'qblog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/django/'
)

# Markdown
MARKDOWN_EDITOR_SKIN = 'simple'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
```

Please let me know if there's anything I may have overlooked. Thanks/

Comment: check for error are there errors?

Comment: @Pekka I don't get any errors. When I run the server, I get the ckeditor widget on the landing page.

Comment: Did you run collectstatic and did you add in the url config?

Comment: @dan-klasson I tried running the collectstatic command and it raised
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a systefilesystem path.

How can I correct this? I'm using django 1.8 and I thought I didn't need to change the STATIC_ROOT setting....

Comment: @dan-klasson and yes I added the url config :)

Comment: @dan-klasson okay now here's the problem: when I run the collect static command, it says System can not find the path specified: 'C:\\django'
That's because I have django in a virtualenv.
How can I let it know to look for django in the virtualenv?

Comment: You run the command in the virtualenv. Does it work on your local though? Because the collectstatic should only be for production

Comment: @dan-klasson I'm using my command prompt with the virtualenv activated. It's worked for controlling everything on my project before.
I didn't know that collectstatic was only for production... I'm just trying to get my ckeditor working in development

Comment: Try checking your console log in your browser for any js errors.